# History behind reproducible research tools and literate programming

Tags: reproducible-research

Reproducibility was talked about by Robert Boyle in 17th century. Literate Programming was invented in 1984 by Donald Knuth. Reproducible Research tools like R markdown were invented recently. My query is : After the invention of Literate Programming, how did the trend of making reproducible reports start? How did tools from R Markdown evolve AFTER the invention of tools like WEB and noweb.

Answer (score 1):

*[This answer was written for the original question, which has since been substantially edited.]*

The question is backwards: if anything, it's [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) which would have been inspired by reproducible research.

The concept of [reproducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility) is closely related to the criterion of [falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability). This concept and its significance in science obviously predates literate programming (and anything related to computer science). More generally, the [scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) has been a pillar of scientific research for a long time. In particular the importance of reproducibility in research is definitely not limited to computer science.

It happens that literate programming can be useful to address the specific problems of reproducibility in modern computer science research, especially in experiments involving machine learning and massive amounts of data ([related example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/137169/93566)). But as far as I know it was not designed in this specific goal, even if it shares some of the principles of the scientific method (transparency, interpretability).

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. Reproducibility was talked about by Robert Boyle in 17th century. Literate Programming was invented in 1984 by Donald Knuth. Reproducible Research tools like R markdown were invented recently. My query is : After the invention of Literate Programming, how did the trend of making reproducible reports start. ?

Comment: You seem to think of this as a discrete process made of inventions which change the way people work, but the reality is much smoother. People were writing papers  describing reproducible research long before tools such as R markdown. It's true that these tools are useful in the perspective of reproducible experimental research, but  github or before that CSV and SVN were useful tools too. The "trend" of making reproducible reports is just the continuation of this process.

Comment: Is an R Markdown file an example of BOTH Literate Programming and Reproducible Reseach? [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming says : Similar to Jupyter Notebooks, R Notebooks are a method of literate programming that allows for direct interaction with R (support for Python, SQL, and Bash are also explicitly named) while producing a reproducible document with publication-quality output. ] I think there is a difference between LP and RR. We may have one without the other. LP = document your code beautifully for a person to read while RR = share code and data.

Comment: @user2338823 of course there is a difference between LP and RR! you insist on putting these two concepts on the same level to compare them: it's true that they overlap, but they are very different concepts in scope and in depth. Sure some R markdown documents (not all) can be considered as examples of reproducible research, but so can thousands of papers published every year as well, and not only in CS. In CS many github repositories are examples of RR as well. You are essentially comparing what is mostly a technology (R markdown or Python Jupyter) against a scientific principle (RR).

Comment: I was reading the history behind these 2 (LP and RR) recently. It's not documented as to whether R Markdown is implementing LP or RR. There are references to BOTH in R Markdown literature. It was not clear to me whether R Markdown is an implentation of LP or RR while reading the docs. Hence my query. Seems like R Markdown implements both LP and RR.

Comment: LP is a a programming paradigm, so it can be implemented (and R markdown certainly implements a good part of it, if not all). But RR is a scientific principle, so there's no such thing as "implementing" RR in general. You are using a definition of RR restricted to programming, i.e. losing 99% of what RR covers.

Comment: Now that you put it in those words, I think I understand it better. Thank you.

Comment: RR ( = Reproducible Research ) I think can be fully done by R Markdown. The Replicable Research paradigm is not implementable by R Markdown/ or any other programming language because it is not related to programming. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. RR is much more general than programming, it's used in any kind of experimental research, e.g. medicine.